# Some of my hyperlinks in Rich Text Box won't launch to web browser. WHY?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have a problem with my rich text box in VB.

I have one list box containing many document titles.
When user clicks on each of the title, hyperlinks will appear in the rich text box below.

But somehow,
some of the hyperlinks won't work.
some of them when I click, it will launch.
Some of them remain static.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgtar.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yygI.png]

I put random names for example only because my documents are proprietary and confidential.

As you can see,  when I click on google.com, it will launch to google.com
but when I click on facebook.com, it wont go.

I did the LinkClicked event for rich text box and I put True for DetectURLs.

Comment: Does the LinkClicked event fire for facebook.URL?

Comment: i put this code: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.LinkText) <<this means fire for all hyperlinks right?

Comment: Put a messagebox instead to test it in easier and more obvious way. Also please [edit] your question and ensure it contains all necessary information for debugging question, otherwise it will collect close votes.

Comment: Put message box? What do you mean by that, exactly?

Comment: See the [`MsgBox()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd(v=vs.90).aspx) function. Then please extend your question by all your findings. On this site, comments are for purpose of commenting. The page [ask] could help you.